# Why does the C++ compiler allow extern keyword combined with definition?

Tags: c++, extern

I accidentally made an error using the `extern` keyword and then discovered that the compiler allowed my line of code. Why is the following program allowed? Does the compiler strip off the extern keyword? It does not even give a warning.

```
#include <iostream>

extern void test() { std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl; };

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this isn't allowed?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler (some anyway) prepend `extern` by default?

Comment: C compilers also allow it (and I tend to guess that the standard allows it as well).

Comment: Functions have external linkage by default. `extern void test` and `void test` are equivalent.

Comment: @MariusBancila: So the only way it would trigger a compilation error is when combined with `static`?

Comment: I thought that extern implies that the definition is at different location.

Comment: `extern` tells the compiler that the symbol (function-name in this case) resolution is postponed until linkage. According to @MariusBancila's comment above, that's the default behavior in any case, so you could have equivalently just declared the function without `extern` and without implementation (by the way, it would not be possible to do the same with a variable, since the declaration of a variable also embeds its instantiation).

Comment: You've explicitly said `test()` has external linkage, which it would have anyway.  That's no more obnoxious than using say `unsigned int` where simply `unsigned` would have done, or `inline void f() { }` for an in-class member function that's implicitly inline anyway... heaps of such examples if you start digging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not unusual, in fact,  C++ internally does that exact same thing, note what 1.4/6 says:

> The templates, classes, functions, and objects in the library have external linkage

The templates in the library very obviously have definitions, too. And why wouldn't they!

See what 3.1/2 and 3.4/2 (emphasis added) have to say:

> A declaration is a definition unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body (8.4), **[or]** it contains the extern specifier (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification25 (7.5) **and** neither an initializer nor a functionbody
>   [...]
>   When a name has external linkage , the entity it denotes **can** be referred to by names from scopes of other translation units or from other scopes of the same translation unit.

Your declaration has a function body, so it is a definition, and that's explicitly, perfectly allowable. The function has external linkage, which means you **could** refer to it by a name from a scope in another translation unit, but you're not *required* to do that.

You're still perfectly allowed to call it by its name in the current translation unit, and that is what you are doing.

Note that there's a clause about names at namespace scope, so your usage of the `extern` keyword is somewhat redundant anyway.